# Record function in Jmeter results in a error message

Tags: jmeter

I recently downloaded and installed Jmeter 2.11. afterwards I tried the record functionality of the program, but that resulted in an error message:
“Could not create script recording proxy – see log for detail”.

I have try modifying the “environment variables”, but that does not help.

In the Log from the application the following message was shown.

2014/08/19 10:23:02 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: **Could not open/read key store C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\proxyserver.jks** (The system cannot find the file specified) 
2014/08/19 10:23:02 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Creating Proxy CA in C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2014/08/19 10:23:02 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: Could not initialise key store java.io.IOException: Command :'keytool -genkeypair -alias :root_ca: -dname "CN=_ DO NOT INSTALL unless this is your certificate (JMeter root CA), OU=Username: TATG, C=US" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass {redacted) -keypass {redacted) -validity 7 -ext bc:c' failed, code: 1
Illegal option:  -ext
Try keytool -help

```
at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.genkeypair(KeyToolUtils.java:168)
at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateProxyCA(KeyToolUtils.java:230)
```

I notice the proxyserver.jks is missing under the bin directory.

How can I resolve this problem or get a copy of this file(ie. hack the directory)?

Answer (score 0):

Read this, it answers exactly this issue:

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/TestRecording210